# Wordpress Subdomain logging solution

Tags: wordpress, authentication, logging, subdomain, multisite

How to link two WordPress websites sign-in option, Example I have a subdomain with BuddyPress and main site,
Then the site should function as, when I click on sign-in on the main site, it should redirect it in a subdomain and after logging in back to main site with logged in.

Thanks in advance.